# Doctor's Bedroom

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who season 6 episode 4  "The Doctor's Wife," at the end of the episode Rory asks the doctor if he had a room. Does anyone know if that meant something?

Comment: I would recommend making the title summarize the question.

Comment: I imagine it was supposed to provide a reminder that The Doctor is not human.

Answer (score 6):

This comes after The Doctor mentions that, since all the bedrooms in the TARDIS had been erased, they need to create a new one for Amy and Rory.  The couple request a normal double bed, as appropriate for a married couple, but the Doctor instead talks up bunk beds, like the pair had been forced to use previously.

So Rory's question carries several implications.  There is the implied question of whether the Doctor even sleeps, or whether he is perpetually a manic time lord busybody.  More specifically, Rory is suggesting that maybe the Doctor should just worry about his own bedroom:  that is, he should mind his own business and let Amy and Rory have the room they want.  It also insinuates that the Doctor does not even really understand what normal people might want in a bedroom.

Answer (score 4):

Timelords rarely sleeping or catching naps in odd places is something borne out in the old series. Here's a few more possible implications.

1) That the Doctor is private enough that they have never even seen his room, yet he knows all about theirs.

2) The Doctor spends all his time in the main room of the TARDIS where the TARDIS consciousness is most concentrated. In effect, his bedroom is the console room. He sleeps with the TARDIS...

3) It has occured to Rory for the very first time that he has no idea where the Doctor sleeps. They had been so focused on where they had been sleeping and their own conditions--with no idea where the Doctor slept. Rory is normally empathetic, so it's struck him two fold. First he's a bit gobsmacked that he's never noticed that he didn't know, second, it drives home that maybe the Doctor REALLY doesn't understand why they would need something other than bunk beds because he's so alien. Maybe it's because he doesn't sleep, but it also implies a real difference between humans and Time Lords.

Context is kind of "while we're on the subject of bedrooms, wait just a second, do you even have one yourself?"